# What is the complexity of finding e^(A) for a Hermitian matrix A?

Tags: space-complexity, linear-algebra

If A is a hermitian matrix of size NxN .What is the order of no. of steps required to compute e^(A).How to prove it?

Comment: (I don't quite see the link between `no. of steps required` and [tag:space-complexity].)

Comment: What is your computation model?

Comment: Action of Hamiltonian